# Page Navigation using Linq to objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, wcf

I have a WCF service and a MVC client which shows logs from a database. I have done so that i take 20 logs from the database and puts it in a list based on resent date and shows it in a table.

Controller:

```
if(model.SelectedSystemId == null)
{
    model.SelectedSystemId = model.Systems.First().Value;
}

model.Entries = _svc.getLogsByHostName(model.SelctedSystemId).ToList();

const int PageSize = 20;
var PageNumber = page ?? 1;
model.Entries = model.Entries.ToPageList(PageNumber, PageSize).ToList();
reurn View(model);
```

Now i have a regular page navigation which i havent done anything with.

Index:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
<ul class="pagination">
    <li>
        <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now the thing that i want to do is that. When you navigate, i want to use linq to reload the page and get the next 20 logs from the databse based on Date.
It should look something like this

```
var range = sortedList.Skip(pageSize*(pageNumber - 1)).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

How can i use linq and my html navigation bar to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `PageListPager` tag helper, which is the part of the `PageList` library, it can be added to your MVC project through Nuget. Here is the [GitHub](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) page.

Comment: real paging in all DB's isn't supported. I believe that paging is introduced for mssql from mssql 2014. Other DB's might already support it.

Comment: I used PageListPager and it worked fine! Thank you for your answer. @SeM